# Authorization fails with large ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I can successfully make a POST via ajax to a controller that has an [Authorize] attribute and pass in an array (JSON encoded).

When I make the same request with a large array (around 3,000) numeric Ids, I immediately get a 401 returned by the Authorize attribute and the action method never gets executed.

Why would a large payload affect the Authorization attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add this to your web.config

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="1200" />
```

as you could well be over the default limit ([4mb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)), above sets it to 2gb

Comment: I had already increased the maxRequestLength, but since this was a JSON field, turns out I also needed to increase <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="900000" />. Thnx!